# Tkinter : NameError: name 'equation' is not defined

Tags: python, tkinter

I have following code. I cannot press any of buttons I've created, because I've got an error:
`NameError: name 'equation' is not defined` on every single button. What is wrong with this? I'm new to Python. I've tried placing this chunk of code which includes equation in different places (outside class, in main() func), but none of this worked for me

```py
from tkinter import * 

expression = ""


class Calc(Frame):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.UI()

    def UI(self):

        equation = StringVar()

        equation.set("0")

        large_font = ('Arial', 30)

        self.master.title("Kalkulator")
        self.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = 1)

        calc_txt = Entry(width = 204, font = large_font, bg = "gray", fg = "white", textvariable = equation)
        calc_txt.place(x = 0 , y = 0)

        percentage_btn = Button(width = 6, height = 2, text = "%", bg = "orange", fg = "white", borderwidth=2, relief="solid", command = lambda: press("%"))
        percentage_btn.place(x = 0, y = 49)

        sqr_btn = Button(width = 6, height = 2, text = "^", bg = "orange", fg = "white", borderwidth=2, relief="solid", command = lambda: press("**"))
        sqr_btn.place(x = 51, y = 49)

        sqr_root_btn = Button(width = 6, height = 2, text = "", bg = "orange", fg = "white", borderwidth=2, relief="solid", command = lambda: press(3))
        sqr_root_btn.place(x = 102, y = 49)

        multiply_btn = Button(width = 6, height = 2, text = "*", bg = "orange", fg = "white", borderwidth=2, relief="solid", command = lambda: press("*"))
        multiply_btn.place(x = 153, y = 49)

        divide_btn = Button(width = 6, height = 2, text = "/", bg = "orange", fg = "white", borderwidth=2, relief="solid", command = lambda: press("/"))
        divide_btn.place(x = 153, y = 89)

        add_btn = Button(width = 6, height = 2, text = "+", bg = "orange", fg = "white", borderwidth=2, relief="solid", command = lambda: press("+"))
        add_btn.place(x = 153, y = 129)

        substrct_btn = Button(width = 6, height = 2,  text = "-", bg = "orange", fg = "white", borderwidth=2, relief="solid", command = lambda: press("-"))
        substrct_btn.place(x = 153, y = 169)

        equal_btn = Button(width = 6, height = 2, text = "=", bg = "orange", fg = "white", borderwidth=2, relief="solid", command = equalpress)
        equal_btn.place(x = 153, y = 209)

        clear_btn = Button(width = 6, height = 2, text = "C", bg = "red", fg = "white", borderwidth=2, relief="solid", command = clear)
        clear_btn.place(x = 0, y = 209)

        dot_btn = Button(width = 6, height = 2,  text = ".", bg = "white", fg = "black", borderwidth=2, relief="solid", command = lambda: press("."))
        dot_btn.place(x = 51, y = 209)

        zero_btn = Button(width = 6, height = 2, text = "0", bg = "white", fg = "black", borderwidth=2, relief="solid", command = lambda: press(0))
        zero_btn.place(x = 102, y = 209)

        one_btn = Button(width = 6, height = 2, text = "1", bg = "white", fg = "black", borderwidth=2, relief="solid", command = lambda: press(1))
        one_btn.place(x = 0, y = 169)

        two_btn = Button(width = 6, height = 2, text = "2", bg = "white", fg = "black", borderwidth=2, relief="solid", command = lambda: press(2))
        two_btn.place(x = 51, y = 169)

        three_btn = Button(width = 6, height = 2, text = "3", bg = "white", fg = "black", borderwidth=2, relief="solid", command = lambda: press(3))
        three_btn.place(x = 102, y = 169)

        four_btn = Button(width = 6, height = 2, text = "4", bg = "white", fg = "black", borderwidth=2, relief="solid", command = lambda: press(4))
        four_btn.place(x = 0, y = 129)

        five_btn = Button(width = 6, height = 2, text = "5", bg = "white", fg = "black", borderwidth=2, relief="solid", command = lambda: press(5))
        five_btn.place(x = 51, y = 129)

        six_btn = Button(width = 6, height = 2, text = "6", bg = "white", fg = "black", borderwidth=2, relief="solid", command = lambda: press(6))
        six_btn.place(x = 102, y = 129)

        seven_btn = Button(width = 6, height = 2, text = "7", bg = "white", fg = "black", borderwidth=2, relief="solid", command = lambda: press(7))
        seven_btn.place(x = 0, y = 89)

        eight_btn = Button(width = 6, height = 2, text = "8", bg = "white", fg = "black", borderwidth=2, relief="solid", command = lambda: press(8))
        eight_btn.place(x = 51, y = 89)

        nine_btn = Button(width = 6, height = 2, text = "9", bg = "white", fg = "black", borderwidth=2, relief="solid", command = lambda: press(9))
        nine_btn.place(x = 102, y = 89)


def press(num): 
    
    global expression 
  
    expression = expression + str(num) 

    equation.set(expression)


def equalpress(): 
    
    try:

        global expression

        total = str(eval(expression))

        equation.set(total)

        expression = ""

    except:

        equation.set(" error ")
        expression = ""


def clear(): 
    global expression 
    expression = "" 
    equation.set("") 


def main():

    window = Tk()
    window.resizable(0,0)
    window.geometry("204x250")
    app = Calc()
    window.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: `equation` is only defined in the scope of `UI`, once the function runs that variable is gone. You have to define it somewhere else so it's always in scope. You already did that with `expression` so I'm not sure where the confusion lies, unless you didn't write that code.

Comment: If i'd put all this functions (equalpress, press, clear) in same place, where `expression` is I'd still got exactly the same error. Solution provided by Novel solved my problem.

EDIT: Or maybe you know something, that I don't. :D

Comment: I meant, do something like `equation = StringVar()` at the top of the file, similar to how you did `expression = ""`. The accepted answer that uses the class is a better solution though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the expression variable and all your functions in your class, and then give all variables that you want to be 'global' a name that starts with `self.` instead. Like this:

```
from tkinter import *

class Calc(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.UI()

    def UI(self):
        self.equation = StringVar()
        self.equation.set("0")
        self.expression = ''
        large_font = ('Arial', 30)
        calc_txt = Entry(width = 204, font = large_font, bg = "gray", fg = "white", textvariable = self.equation)
        calc_txt.place(x = 0 , y = 0)

        percentage_btn = Button(width = 6, height = 2, text = "%", bg = "orange", fg = "white", borderwidth=2, relief="solid", command = lambda: self.press("%"))
        percentage_btn.place(x = 0, y = 49)

    def press(self, num):
        self.expression = self.expression + str(num)
        self.equation.set(self.expression)

def main():
    window = Tk()
    window.resizable(0,0)
    window.geometry("204x250")
    app = Calc()
    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It's working as it should be right now. May I ask if you know any simpler solution to position all buttons? Or maybe should I reconsider using other GUI package like PySimpleGUI?

Comment: Yes, you should use the pack() or grid() managers instead. Using place() is well known to be a waste of time.

Comment: @Katvunis here, I refactored your code for you: https://pastebin.com/S9FKpTJS